Mahasi Sayadaw's approach and vagueness in the Tipitaka suttas
Mahasi Sayadaw's approach isn't valid because it attempts to fill in the gaps with commentary from monastics that are supposed to be highly attained? Are there no gaps or vagueness in the Buddha's Tipitaka teachings? If there are gaps or vagueness withing the Buddha's Tipitaka scriptures, can an attempt to fill the gaps in the Buddha's teaching ever be done mindfully, with humility and respect? Also, if a spiritual teaching has gaps or is vague, can there be some kind of a good reason for it being that way?

Related: Sutta jhana vs. Visuddhimagga jhana

Related: What You Might Not Know about Jhāna & Samādhi by Kumāra Bhikkhu

You really need to reformat this question, your wording makes your question vague! I don't understand what you are asking.  What are these gaps you are equating?

There are no gaps in the Buddha's teaching.

The Blessed One answered him, saying: "What more does the community of bhikkhus expect from me, Ananda? I have set forth the Dhamma without making any distinction of esoteric and exoteric doctrine; there is nothing, Ananda, with regard to the teachings that the Tathagata holds to the last with the closed fist of a teacher who keeps some things back".
DN 16

The primary gap that actually exists is not understanding the words the Buddha spoke.
For example, the words "sabbakaya" found in the meditation teachings. Even though "sabbakaya" literally means "all bodies"; even though the relevant sutta literally says there are multiple "bodies"; even though the only commentary within the Sutta Pitaka, namely, the Patisambiddhamagga, literally says "sabbakaya" refers to two bodies, namely, the mental body & the physical body, Theravada monks & scholars continue to insist "sabbakaya" means "the whole body".
For example, even though the word "jati" is literally defined as the birth of "beings" and even though the word "beings" ("satta") is literally defined as "a view", Theravada monks & scholars continue to insist "jati" means "physical birth".
When words are not understood, this leaves gaps requiring explanations the Buddha never spoke, such as saying two conditions of depenent origination are a past life, eight conditions are the present life and two conditions are a future life. In this way, there are more & more gaps, filled with more & more explanations the Buddha never spoke.

The Buddha passed into Paranibanna before written language, so I would assume that, even though many monks, especially those close to him like Ananda, may still have some inconsistenties. It's almost untenable to think otherwise. As far as trying to fill in the gaps by even a greatly renowned Buddhist scholar would be futile, because the inconsistencies were there previous to their interpretation of the Tipitaka.
